# Append unique tooltip to last item in table row inside a JQuery foreach loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append a tooltip to the last item in a row of data that is unique for each row, but when I append the newest items tooltip, it overwrite the tooltip of the previous rows.

This is what I want is:

- ID     | Name
- 933435 | item 1 - on hovering over it it should say "The items name is: item 1".
- 877988 | item 2 - on hovering over it it should say "The items name is: item 2".
- 746468 | item 3 - on hovering over it it should say "The items name is: item 3".

But this is what I get:

- ID     | Name
- 933435 | item 1 - on hovering over it says "The items name is: item 3".
- 877988 | item 2 - on hovering over it says "The items name is: item 3".
- 746468 | item 3 - on hovering over it says "The items name is: item 3".

It appends the tooltip to every last table item in each row, rather than to the last item of the last added row.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {

            // create row of data
            items = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + val.itemID + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + val.itemName + '</td>'
                '</tr>';

            // appends the created row to the body of the table
            $('tbody').append(items);

            // appends a unique tooltip to the end of the added row
            $('td:last-child').attr('title', 'The items name is: ' + val.itemName);

        });
```

Is there a way to get around this issue without putting the tooltip in the table items decleration like `'<td title="">'`? I'm trying to not do it that way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending a string you can append a jQuery object and modify the `td` in that object

When you wrap a valid snippet of html in `$()` you can use jQuery methods on the resulting object the same way as if they are already in the page

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {

  // create row of data
  var $items = $('<tr>' +
    '<td>' + val.itemID + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + val.itemName + '</td>'
    '</tr>');

  // only apply tooltip to the current row
  $items.find('td:last').attr('title', 'The items name is: ' + val.itemName);

  // appends the created row to the body of the table
  $('tbody').append($items);



});
```

Alternatively change your selector so it only looks in the last row

```
$('tbody tr:last td:last').attr('title....
```

What is currently happening is you are looping through all existing last children in every iteration of the loop overwriting all existing ones not just the new one

Comment: Thank you, that accomplished what I was looking for.